# php my sql pagination help need for links and advancing the next offset

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

hi i'm trying to paginate a php mysql database, and I can't figure out what make the results move to the next page, it's stuck at record row zero and what do i change to make it go to the next set of results? is this the offset hooked to the nav link somehow does it have to recall a mysql query? how does this work?

```
    //pagination
    //find out how many rows are in the table 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM hotels_database";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $con) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
    $r = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $numrows = $r[0];


    // number of rows to show per page
    $rowsperpage = 2;
    // find out total pages
    $totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);

    // get the current page or set a default
    if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {
    // cast var as int
    $currentpage = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','', $_GET['currentpage']);
    } else {
    // default page num
    $currentpage = 1;
    } // end if



    // if current page is greater than total pages...
    if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {
    // set current page to last page
    $currentpage = $totalpages;
    } // end if
    // if current page is less than first page...
    if ($currentpage < 1) {
    // set current page to first page
    $currentpage = 1;
    } // end if

    // the offset of the list, based on current page 
    $offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;

    // get the info from the db 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM hotels_database LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $con) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

    // while there are rows to be fetched...
    while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // echo data


    for ($stars=1;$stars<=floor($list['stars']);$stars++){
    $star_string .= "<img src='images/star.jpg'/>";

    }

    if (($list['stars']-floor($list['stars']))> 0){
    $star_string .= "<img src='images/half_star.jpg'/>";
    }

    $hotels_database .= "<div style='display:table-row;height:70px;'><div style='width:60px;height:60px;display:table-cell;float:left;'><img src='".$list['pic']."' width='60px'/></div>"."<div style='width:280px;display:table-cell;vertical-align:top;text-align:left;padding-left:5px;font-size:12px;'><a href='#' class='database_link'>".$list['hotel']."</a>".$star_string."<br/><span style='font-size:10px;'>".$list['addy']."</span><br/>Guest score: <span style='color:red;font-size:14px;'>".$list['score']."</span> out of 10"."<br/>"."<li class='database_arrow'>Display Amenities & More Info</li>"."</div>"."<div style='width:78px;height:60px;display:table-cell;vertical-align:top;'><span style='font-family:arial;color:green;font-size:15px;'>$".$list['price']."</span><br/>per night<div style='border-radius:10px;background-color:#1284d3;height:25px;width:70px;left:10px;top:10px;position:relative;border:1px black solid;color:white;font-family:arial;line-height:8px;'><br/>select</div><br/></div>"."</div><hr style='color:#c8ff78;'/>";

    $star_string="";
    } // end while

    /******  build the pagination links ******/
    // range of num links to show



    //pagination
    /*
```

ya, so i can't figure out how to go to the next offset what href do i use in this case? and why isn't the currentpage query string being displayed in my addy bar? please take a look,

Comment: You should show some of your PHP code, but in essence, you'll want to pass the start value (page or record) back to PHP.

Comment: you may want to see if the links are getting the offset number correct. What can happen is that the `for` loop is not advancing the offset as it spits out links so they all say `?offset=0` not link1 `?offset=0` , link2 `?offset=1` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

As D.N said code would be helpful but in general it goes

`if(isset($_GET['offset']) {`

`$offset = $_get['offset'];`

`}`

`else{`

`$offset = 0;`

`}`

then in the SQL call you add:

`'what ever the call is' "limit $limit offset $offset"`

Comment: this is not the preferred method with MySQL, but rather `LIMIT $offset,$number_of_rows_to_fetch`

Comment: I was not trying to get a full description of the process or how to secure it. There is a lot better was to do it but this is the most common and I would guess close to how he (just starting out, I would guess) is going at it. But yes, this is not preferred.

Comment: I just read some literature on SQL, and it seems that with SQL:2008, the most recent sql standard, your version is the preferred method.